Add labels next to inputs of ArrayField on edit page
I have a property named myArray which returns array like this:
'#1' => 100000,
'#2' => 67400,
'#3' => 0,
....

I have a CRUD controller where I added this property like this:
    yield ArrayField::new('myArray')
        ->setFormTypeOption('allow_add', false)
        ->setFormTypeOption('allow_delete', false)
        ->setTemplatePath('admin/fields/array.html.twig');

I have a custom twig to make it look nice on index page.
On edit page it looks like this:

Array values are shown as textboxes. Is it possible to show array keys as labels and put them somewhere next to textboxes?

Can you not do this in admin/fields/array.html.twig?

@ChrisHaas, yes but I do not know how

Can you post the contents of that file?
